# Amazon product advertising API offers are always 0

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having a little play around with Amazons product advertising API but I cant seen to get a price of any item.

I am using the response group of Medium which does return an offers summary section but everything is zero and it is like this no matter what I search for.

```
[OfferSummary] => SimpleXMLElement Object
          (
            [TotalNew] => 0
            [TotalUsed] => 0
            [TotalCollectible] => 0
            [TotalRefurbished] => 0
          )
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

EDIT

Now I can get the price of an item from the ItemAttributes array. This however is not present for all products. A typical scenario for me is I get a set of 10 products but only 5 ( sometimes less ) will have a price associated to it. Again the Offer Summary is still 0 for everything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you got an Associate ID set up?

Comment: Yep I have everything set up correctly because I am able to get results, I will update the post with some new information

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a combination of ListPrice in ItemAttributes and FormattedPrice from the OfferSummary Response Group (both found in 'Medium'). So cross out ListPrice if FormattedPrice exists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my issue is that in some cases the ListPrice section is not there and everything in the OfferSummary section is zero. So no matter what I am unable to get a price for the product. I am using the Medium response group.